# Variables inside Functions (Corona Lua)

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I've searched everywhere for an answer on how to change a variable inside a function. I have tried many different solutions but none have worked so far.

My plan is to change a variable named 'stateRed' inside a function which is run when a button is pressed. When the function is run, the variables will change to 'READY'. I will then use this variable to run a separate chunk of code (the actual game). There are two of these buttons.

My code looks something like this:

```
function ReadyRed()
stateRed = 'READY'
stateBtnRed = widget.newButton
{
    defaultFile = "ready_red.png",
    overFile = "unready_red.png",
    label = "Ready",
    emboss = true,
    onPress = unreadyStateRed,
}
stateBtnRed.rotation = 90; stateBtnRed.width = 90; stateBtnRed.height = 90; stateBtnRed.x = display.contentWidth / 2 - 170; stateBtnRed.y = display.contentHeight - 270
return stateRed
end

function UnreadyRed()
local stateRed = 'UNREADY'
stateBtnRed = widget.newButton
{
    defaultFile = "unready_red.png",
    overFile = "ready_red.png",
    label = "Unready",
    emboss = true,
    onPress = readyStateRed,
}
stateBtnRed.rotation = 90; stateBtnRed.width = 90; stateBtnRed.height = 90; stateBtnRed.x = display.contentWidth / 2 - 170; stateBtnRed.y = display.contentHeight - 270
return stateRed
end
```

The code that starts the game looks like this:

```
if stateRed == 'READY' and stateBlue == 'Ready' then
```

Comment: Is `stateRed` global or local variable?

Comment: In your code you defined two different variables named the same  `stateRed`. One is global and second is local (it exists only in `UnreadyRed` function).

Comment: stateRed is a global variable

Answer (score 2):

If variable `stateRed` is global then remove `local` keyword stand before variable name i.e.

```
function UnreadyRed()
    stateRed = 'UNREADY'
    ...
end
```

Note:

- You probably don't need return `stateRed` in `ReadyRed` and `UnreadyRed` functions since  `stateRed` is global variable.
- Use one notation style. I recommended you [Camel Case notation](https://sanaulla.info/2008/06/25/camelcase-notation-naming-convention-for-programming-languages/)